# Expected value of product of correlated variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to compute the expected value $E[\alpha_1\beta_1\alpha_2\beta_2]$, where the $\alpha$'s are independent of the $\beta$'s, but $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are correlated and $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are correlated.

Is this equivalent to $E[\alpha_1\alpha_2]*E[\beta_1\beta_2]$? It seems right to me because we can define $X=\alpha_1\alpha_2$ and $Y=\beta_1\beta_2$, and $X$ and $Y$ should still be independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution: if "the $\alpha$'s are independent of the $\beta$'s" means each $\alpha_i$ is independent of each $\beta_j$, then $\alpha_1 \alpha_2$ is not
necessarily independent of $\beta_1 \beta_2$.  For example, for two independent fair coin flips let

- $\alpha_1 = 1$ if the first flip is Heads, $-1$ otherwise
- $\alpha_2 = 1$ if the second flip is Heads, $-1$ otherwise
- $\beta_1 = 1$ if the first and second flips are equal, $-1$ otherwise

Then $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$ are independent, $\alpha_2$ and $\beta_1$ are independent, but $\alpha_1 \alpha_2 \beta_1 = 1$ always.

However, if "the $\alpha$'s are independent of the $\beta$'s" means the
pair $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$ is independent of the pair $(\beta_1, \beta_2)$, 
then you are correct: any function of $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ is independent of
any function of $\beta_1, \beta_2$.